# Android - View change according to keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I am working on an Android app, and want to implement similar effect like Path:

According to the screenshot below, please note that there's some content (share buttons,  the "I'm with..." and "I'm at..." buttons)right above the keyboard:

[image: When keyboard open]

and when the keyboard closed, the content dropped to the bottom of the page:

[image: When keyboard closed]

I was wondering how we can detect the height of the keyboard and dynamically change view to have this effect? Please share some code pointers or examples. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a layout yet? There is nothing special in doing something like this. Make the view align parent bottom and make the `softInputMode=resize` What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `softInputMode` for your activity.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.example.yourapp"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

More information on softInputModes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

You can then create a RelativeLayout with a full-width bottom bar, like so

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:align_parentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BOTTOM BAR" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
 in android manifest for that particular activity.